# Function name from offset?

Tags: debugging, crash

If I have some information like:

```
AppName: myapp.exe   
AppVer: x.x.x.x  
ModName: kernel32.dll 
ModVer: 5.1.2600.3541    
Offset: 00012a6b
```

Is it possible for me to determine what function exists at offset 00012a6b in kernel32.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they're called dll viewer programs. this is just one example from a quick websearch. but yes they exist

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

Comment: That works; now is there a place where I can download that specific version of kernel32.dll?

Comment: no idea about that one dude. i'd imagine that would be pretty hard to find without microsoft contacts

Answer (score 5):

start windbg, load your app and execute

```
ln address
```

in the debugger and it will print the closest symbol.